# How do I match this in as a regex expression

Tags: regex

How do I match a string using a regular expression to match any combination of the following characters:

```
Y M D
```

That is, the following strings should match...as long as it contains any number of those characters:

```
YYYYMMDD
blahYYMMDD
c:\mydir\YYYYDDMM
YYDD
DD
MMYYDD
...etc
```

All of those should match...as long as those characters occur in succession, it should match.  What would the regex be?

Comment: None of these are really what I am looking for.  I want to match (and extract) any substring containing any combination of "Y", "M", or "D" characters and I only want to extract the Y, M, D, characters.  They can be in any number, any combination but as long as a Y, M, or D character is containing in a contiguous string, I want to extract that contiguous string of characters.  So in my examples the values returned would be:  "YYYYMMDD", "YYMMDD", "YYYYDDMM", "YYDD", "DD", "MMYYDD"

Comment: I figured it ou, If I want to extract that portion then the regex would be:

([YMD]+)/

Comment: Did you see my first example of `/[YMD]{2,}/`? I think that does exactly what you're asking. Unless you also want match just one character (not 2 or more), in which case you're right: `/[YMD]+/`.

Answer (score 1):

Two or more of `Y`, `M`, or `D` in a row (e.g., `MY`, `DD`, or `YD`)?

```
/[YMD]{2,}/
```

---

Or do you mean where any of those individual letters occurs twice or more in a row (i.e., `YY`, `MM`, or `DD`)?

```
/Y{2,}|M{2,}|D{2,}/
```

You could also get a little fancy with a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
# one of [YMD] followed by another one of whichever letter matched

/([YMD])(?=\1)/
```

Comment: How would I say YMD followed by any number of occurrences of [YMD]?

Comment: @GregH Literal `YMD` followed by any `Y`, `M`, or `D` characters (including none?)? Try `/YMD[YMD]*/`.

Answer (score 0):

I will not be misled by the similarity to date format matching, and take you at your word that you want to match when the string contains a Y and an M and a D, in any order.

This: `'(?=.*M)(?=.*Y)(?=.*D)'`

using positive lookahead assertions.

Comment: Can you provide a comment here containing an explanation of how this regex works exactly?